# Hadoop Yarn 0.23.6 - Going to localhost:8088 gives IPC error on versions

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have configured Hadoop Yarn as per my previous post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499814/hadoop-yarn-0-23-6-starting-scripts-vs-binaries-and-localhost-errors

When going to localhost:8088 I get the following:

ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ���)org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch���>Server IPC version 5 cannot communicate with client version 47

I have been looking around and I cannot find anything explaining why. Any ideas?

Thanks